# error in importing M2Crypto Mac OS X

Tags: python, m2crypto

when I try to import M2Crypto in python, I get following error:

I'm using Mac OS X, python 2.7

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/armita/.python-eggs/M2Crypto-0.22.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg-tmp/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so, 2): Symbol not found: _X509_free
  Referenced from: /Users/armita/.python-eggs/M2Crypto-0.22.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg-tmp/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/armita/.python-eggs/M2Crypto-0.22.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg-tmp/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem solved by installing M2Crypto version 21 or 23, 22 causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing libcrypto.

I've made a script based on [tmiz's solution](https://gist.github.com/tmiz/1441111):

You can check it [here](https://gist.github.com/bernardotorres/de3a87aa13b2e6dc758d).

After you install libssl and libcrypto you can reinstall M2Crypto.